# How to unmarshall XML to this class?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to unmarshall XML using JAXB unmarshaller to the object of this type.

```
public class Pair<T1,T2> implements Serializable {
    private T1 first;

    private T2 second;

    public Pair(T1 first, T2 second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T1 getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(T1 first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public T2 getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(T2 second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}


public class TripPair<T1,T2> extends Pair<T1,T2> {

    public TripPair(T1 first, T2 second) {
        super(first, second);
    }
}

public class Fare extends Pricing implements Comparable<Fare> {

    private List<TripPair<Integer,Integer>> trips = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

XML file

```
<fareGroups>
    <trips>
        <second>37</second>
        <first>0</first>
    </trips>
</fareGroups>
```

XML file have also other data and it is unmarshalled, unfortunately data from elements `first` and `second` are not unmarshalled. I tried to add `@XmlElement` annotations on these fields to `Pair` class, but without sucesss.

**Using `XmlAdapter`**

```
public class PairAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {

    public String marshal(Integer val) throws Exception {
        return val.toString();
    }

    public Integer unmarshal(String val) throws Exception {
        return Integer.valueOf(val);
    }
}

public class Pair<T1,T2> implements Serializable {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PairAdapter.class)
    private T1 first;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PairAdapter.class)
    private T2 second;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a zero-arg constructor, or create an `XmlAdapter` for the `Pair` class to get it to unmarshal correctly (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html).

### UPDATE

> I'm using JAXB marshaller for it and when I made a debugging of
>   non-marshalled element, it has wrong type. ElementNSImpl instead of
>   Integer.

As far as JAXB is concerned `first` and `second` will be treated as type `Object`, since it derives metadata at the class level `Pair` instenad of the type level `Pair<Integer, Integer>`.  Because of this the XML will need to qualify the XML elements with the necessary type information.  This is done using the `xsi:type` attribute.

```
public class Pair<T1,T2> implements Serializable {
    private T1 first;

    private T2 second;
```

Try populating your object model with the data you want and then marshalling it and you will see what the XML should look like for the unmarshal operation.

Comment: I tried to use `XmlAdapter` but it still doesn't work correctly :(

Comment: @misco - When you populate your object model and marshal it what does the resulting XML look like?  Also what does your `XmlAdapter` look like.

Comment: I'm using JAXB marshaller for it and when I made a debugging of non-marshalled element, it has wrong type. ElementNSImpl instead of Integer.

Comment: @misco - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels You haven't explain me rules of accepting the answer. I gave a up-vote every member who wrote me the correct answer.

Comment: @misco: please check the link which explains all. Good luck with your project!